# Is it possible to construct an HTML page in which not all all elements are accessible via CSS selectors/XPaths?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xpath

In other words:

- Are there any HTML constructs that don't allow certain elements to be selected via CSS selectors?
- Are there any HTML constructs that don't allow certain elements to be selected via XPaths?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any HTML constructs that don't allow certain elements to be
>   selected via XPaths?

Yes, some examples:

```
<br>
<p>This is a paragraph.<p>This is another paragraph.
<em><strong>This is some text.</em></strong>
<td rowspan=3>blah</td>
<td rowspan='3">blah</td>
<title>Cars & Trucks</title>
```

There are some HTML to XHTML converters out there that will make it so you can use xPath.  I have used this one in the past:

http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader

Comment: Thanks!  And, if we already have valid XHTML, is there anything that XPath cannot reference?  (I'm assuming the answer is 'no').